# In ios, is it possible to know if the GPS location is not being updated?

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm creating an app that allows the user to navigate with a map when offline (no internet connection or wifi available), and I want to let the user know if the gps location not being updated. I know I can get the last updated location timestamp and the accuracy, but is it possible to know if the gps has no reception?

Comment: What do you mean by "offline"? I'm assuming you mean with no network connectivity.

Comment: Right. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to know if the GPS location is not being updated?

No. It doesn't seem possible given the available API.

There are a few things about GPS to consider, if you haven't already. It is technically possible to receive a location update from `CLLocationManager` when you're "offline" but it will depend on several things:

1. If your device actually has GPS hardware. [Some don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone).
2. If you have line of sight to GPS satellites. There's a difference between [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) and [A-GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

Those true GPS updates will come much less frequently because of the way GPS works, but it should work.

> ... but is it possible to know if the gps has no reception

Based on the way GPS works (as best I understand it) you either turn the radio on/off (`-startUpdatingLocation`/`-stopUpdatingLocation`) with the Location Services API and you either get locations more frequently with A-GPS or infrequently with pure GPS when you don't have a network signal. I don't think the Location Services API has a way of telling you "I don't have a GPS signal at all."

Comment: There are `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy` properties on a `CLLocation` object that you can use to determine how strong the signal is. Generally, a larger accuracy value means the GPS has a weak signal.

Comment: That's a good point, but it doesn't tell you if you have no signal.

Comment: What part of Reachability tells you anything about GPS status? I'm only aware of network status in Reachability.

Comment: @Aaron That's true. Each `CLLocation` also has a timestamp. If the GPS signal is really weak you may not receive a location update at all. It may also call `-locationManager:didFailWithError:`.

Comment: I didn't mean Reachbility tells you about location hardware, my first sentence is misleading.

Comment: After a re-read my original answer was confusing. Reachability is obviously for network detection, not GPS.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no public interface for finding out about the state of specific location hardware such as the GPS receiver.

The Location Manager abstracts all that away, so that developers can get location and accuracy information without worrying about whether the device used GPS, Wifi, iBeacons, cell tower locations, Loran-C, celestial navigation, etc. to determine the location. This is generally a very good thing because it means that your apps work on all devices regardless of whether they have GPS, and will continue to work (and maybe even work better) on new devices that might use other technology. But it also means that you don't get to ask the question "is the device receiving a GPS signal right now?"